# Adding Dlib to my Xcode project but no .h files are found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dlib, xcode9.4

I'm trying to add Dlib to my Xcode project because I want to use facial landmark detection from the Dlib library. I'm completely new to this so I've followed the following article word for word in order to user Dlib- http://prabhu.xyz/2017/05/29/getting-started-with-dlib-on-ios.html

Everything seemed to be going fine but when I try to #include any .h files such as #include  it is telling me the file is not found.

[Screenshot of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9q9Rv.png)

My folder is called DlibTester and is set up as seen in the image below. The Dlib library is in the lib folder.

[Folder set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAT9d.png)

Can someone please help me and suggest where I may be going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry I meant to give the example of #include <dlib/image_processing.h> (which is definitely in the Dlib folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue and it was just a case of me not reading the article properly. I had added a Library Search Path but not a Header Search Path. Dlib seems to be working properly now with Xcode and I can include the .h files.